# Css position child div absolute to grandparent

Tags: css

I am trying to position a div to the bottom right of the window instead of bottom right to its parent div.

Eg

```
<div class="window">

 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Both the `.window` and `.parent` has a `position:relative;`

The `.child` has the styles:

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 10;
right: 10;
```

But this will position it to  `.parent` and not `.window`

Comment: Hi. It's a normal behaviour, the children in absolute position always position compared to the closest parent with a relative position. Try to delete to relative position of the closest parent.

Comment: Also `bottom:10` requires a length unit....like `px` or `em`...so there's that too.

Comment: Have you considered using position: fixed ?

Comment: The fixed position seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic way and we need to consider different cases. If we consider that the parent has no height/width specified, this means that the parent will have the same width as window so the right property is good. For the height, if the parent is the last child of window or there is no the other content the bottom property is also good.

Now if there is elements after the parent, bottom value should be equal to

```
10px - height of all next siblging
```

```css
.window,
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height:50px;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  background:yellow;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(10px - 200px);
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

---

If there is height specified to parent element the same logic will apply since we are considering the bottom, so height of parent has no effect.

If there is width specified to parent element, right property should be

```
10px - (widow-width - parent-width)
```

```css
.window,
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height:50px;
}
.window {
  width:500px;
}
.parent {
  width:200px;
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background:yellow;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(10px - 200px);
  right: calc(10px - (500px - 200px)) ;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="window">

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

So you need to consider in which situation you are and adjust the values as needed. Of course this is not true if your markup is more complex and you have more CSS applied.